# Slow debugging with VS2015 and Trend Micro anti-virus

Tags: visual-studio, antivirus

in our corporation we are using Trend Micro Anti-Virus.
I noticed that when debugging, the "Manages the Trend Micro unauthorized change prevention" process hogs up to 50% CPU usage every time VS is hanged while debugging, and drops down to 0.x% when VS is freed.

We have tried excluding the source code folder from real-time scan but to no avail.

Are there any other ways to fix this? Thank you.

P.S: I know this might not be a SO typical question but as a programmer i cant afford wasting 5 minutes for each mouse-over.

Comment: email the anti-virus maker company and let them know of this situation. hopefully the fix this on their new release.

Comment: Also having this problem. Same behaviour. If I try to inspect a object in debug this Trend Micro proccess start to consume CPU.

Comment: We have sent them an email with this issue but it doesnt look like they know how to fix this

Comment: You'll need to work with your IT dept to get Trend Micro configured such that it no longer causes this issue.  FWIW, we have VS2015 and Trend Micro but I don't have this issue (and also don't have that particular process running as well).

Answer (score 0):

Our IT department spoke with Trend technical support and they were able to fix this issue by excluding several folders (source code, VS installation path and others) from the real-time scan.

Answer (score 0):

I found a blog post about this: http://blog.aabech.no/archive/debugging-happily-alongside-trend-micro/

Pretty much it is saying that you can use the *Trend Micro Performance Tuning Tool* to inspect the slowness of your debugging.

For me an the author of the blog post it was the *msvsmon.exe* which is used for remote debugging and was causing a lot of events which slowed down the whole thing.